# longest common substring in array of strings runtime problem

Tags: c++, runtime-error

```
string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
string res = "";
int i, j;
bool flag = true;

for(int i=0; i<strs[0].size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<strs.size()-1; j++)
    {
        if(strs[j][i] == strs[j+1][i])
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else
            return res;
    }
    if(flag == true)
    {
        res += strs[0][i];
    }
}
return res;
```

}

I was doing this leetcode question where we had to find the longest common prefix of given array of strings and then i got stuck at this i cant understand what is the meaning of this error, most of the test cases are passed so i don't think logic is wrong.Is there any corner cases i am missing?

Runtime Error Message:
Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >' (stl_vector.h)
Last executed input:
[]

Thanks in advance

Comment: `strs` can be empty. You need to change the part `strs[0].size()`.

Comment: Also a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170028/line-933-char-34-runtime-error-reference-binding-to-null-pointer-of-type-str)

Answer (score 1):

Its null pointer exception. So you should check if str is null i.e. str=='" for each string in vector.
and return answer accordingly.

Comment: `strs` is a `vector` type.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant the same for vector of strings